# Is it possible mapping another bean than formatter in hibernate validation 1.1 to usin as UL expression?

Tags: hibernate, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

According to hibernate validation 1.1 reference is possible to use the Unified Expression
Language in constraint violation
messages. This allows to define error messages based on conditional logic and also enables
advanced formatting options. The validation engine makes the following objects available in the
EL context:

- the attribute values of the constraint mapped to the attribute names
- the currently validated value (property, bean, method parameter etc.) under the name *validatedValue*
- **a bean mapped to the name formatter exposing the var-arg method format(String format,
  Object... args) which behaves like java.util.Formatter.format(String format,
  Object... args) .**

There is a class **FormatterWrapper** on org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation package, with this code and which got the funcionality for EL ${formatter}:

```
/**
 * A wrapper class for {@code java.util.Formatter#format} avoiding lookup problems in     EL engines due to
   * ambiguous method resolution for {@code format}.
 *
  * @author Hardy Ferentschik
 */
  public class FormatterWrapper {
private final Formatter formatter;

public FormatterWrapper(Locale locale) {
    this.formatter = new Formatter( locale );
}

public String format(String format, Object... args) {
    return formatter.format( format, args ).toString();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append( "FormatterWrapper" );
    sb.append( "{}" );
    return sb.toString();
}
 }
```

I found on **InterpolationTerm.class** this code related with injection but I don't know how get this contextValues to be modified:

```
private ValueExpression bindContextValues(String messageTemplate, MessageInterpolator.Context messageInterpolatorContext, SimpleELContext elContext) {
    // bind the validated value
    ValueExpression valueExpression = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(
            messageInterpolatorContext.getValidatedValue(),
            Object.class
    );
    elContext.setVariable( VALIDATED_VALUE_NAME, valueExpression );

    // bind a formatter instantiated with proper locale
    valueExpression = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(
            new FormatterWrapper( locale ),
            FormatterWrapper.class
    );
    elContext.setVariable( RootResolver.FORMATTER, valueExpression );

    // map the annotation values
    for ( Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : messageInterpolatorContext.getConstraintDescriptor()
            .getAttributes()
            .entrySet() ) {
        valueExpression = expressionFactory.createValueExpression( entry.getValue(), Object.class );
        elContext.setVariable( entry.getKey(), valueExpression );
    }

    return expressionFactory.createValueExpression( elContext, messageTemplate, String.class );
}
```

So, I wonder...will it is possible to retrieve mapped beans and to add another custom one? I have read JSR 349 api and I didn't find

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to bind another formatter?

Comment: Because, my idea is to reuse the same message for every fields and the same error. So I would like to set a parametized message, p.e: msg.notNull.field=My {0} musn't be null!, and a field, String field with @NotNull(message="#{myBean.replaceToken({msg.notNull.field),name}")

Comment: For this you don't really need another formatter bean. Just use the `addExpressionVariable()` method described in the question I linked to inject the field name and then refer to it via `${name}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Hibernate Validator, you may add custom beans to your error messages as described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702975/building-dynamic-constraintviolation-error-messages). That way you also could bind another formatter bean.

Comment: Thank @Gunnar,but your link send me this question again :P. Could you check it, please?

Comment: Exactly, this's the way! Thank you so much :) But I got two question...what happen with the "new" validator? It's necessary to declare it on some place or automatically replace the default validator? And second: "Note that the parameters specified via addExpressionVariable(String, Object) are global and apply for all constraint violations created by this isValid() invocation. This includes the default constraint violation, but also all violations created by the ConstraintViolationBuilder." So I guess this behavior is only for @Future, isn't? The last line is confusing me.

Comment: You need to register custom validators for built-in constraints via the XML descriptor (the Hibernate Validator reference guide describes the details). Regarding your second question, the objects you set are only "visible" for one particular `isValid()` invocation of that particular constraint validator.