# Hibernate Validator - Dynamic Validation-Message

Tags: java, dynamic, hibernate-validator

I'm having a class `X` that has three fields: `state` (an enum of `A` and `B`), `a` and `b`.
When `state` is `A`, `a` must not be `null`, when `state` is `B`, `b` must not be `null`.

```
@ValidateCondition(message = "Validation failed")
public class X {
  private State state;
  private String a;
  private String b;
}
```

Using hibernate-validator, I've build the following Validator:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidateCondition {
  String message() default "ValidateCondition failed";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class MyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidateCondition, X> {
  @Override
  public boolean isValid(X x, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if(x.getState()==State.A){
      return x.getA() != null;
    }
    if(x.getState()==State.B){
      return x.getB() != null;
    }
  }
}
```

So whenever validation fails, I currently get the message `Validation failed`, but what I want would be a message, telling me why it failed, like `Since state was B, b must not be blank`.

I'm assuming I can somehow use the `ConstraintValidatorContext` for that, but I don't know if or how.

Comment: Hi, check if this is answer to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702975/building-dynamic-constraintviolation-error-messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple:
Just call a context inside isValid area:

```
context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("message here");
```

Enjoy!

Comment: That was it, thanks.
To be complete, I should have disabled the default message with context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation() and added the new one with context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("my custom message").addConstraintViolation().
Thank you